# Scala/Spark: flatten multiple json in RDD using SCALA spark but getting invalid data

Tags: scala, apache-spark

MY CODE preferred in scala for flatten multiple json

```
**val data = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/spark/sample.json")
val nospace = data.map(x => x.trim())
val nospaces = nospace.filter(x => x!="")
val local = nospaces.collect
var vline =""
var eline :List[String]= List()
var lcnt =0
var rcnt =0
local.map{x =>
vline+=x
if (x=="[") lcnt+=1
if (x=="[") rcnt+=1
if (lcnt==rcnt){
eline++=List(vline)
lcnt=0
rcnt=0
vline =""
}
}**
```

MY Input Sheet multiple json file :

```
 [
    {
    “Year”: “2013”,
    “First Name”: “JANE”,
    “County”: “A”,
    “Sex”: “F”,
    “Count”: “27”
    },{
    “Year”: “2013”,
    “First Name”: “JADE”,
    “County”: “B”,
    “Sex”: “M”,
    “Count”: “26”
    },{
    “Year”: “2013”,
    “First Name”: “JAMES”,
    “County”: “C”,
    “Sex”: “M”,
    “Count”: “21”
    }
    ]
```

Comment: Please consider formatting your code before posting. The easier it is to read the more likely you are to get answers. Also please verify that the `**` are indeed part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input json taken

```
root@ubuntu:/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/data# cat /home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/data/sample.json 

[
    {
    "Year": "2013",
    "First Name": "JANE",
    "County": "A",
    "Sex": "F",
    "Count": "27"
    },{
    "Year": "2013",
    "First Name": "JADE",
    "County": "B",
    "Sex": "M",
    "Count": "26"
    },{
    "Year": "2013",
    "First Name": "JAMES",
    "County": "C",
    "Sex": "M",
    "Count": "21"
    }
    ]
```

code to read the json and flatten as dataframe columns

```
spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("file:////home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/data/sample.json").show()

'''
+-----+------+----------+---+----+                                              
|Count|County|First Name|Sex|Year|
+-----+------+----------+---+----+
|   27|     A|      JANE|  F|2013|
|   26|     B|      JADE|  M|2013|
|   21|     C|     JAMES|  M|2013|
+-----+------+----------+---+----+
'''
```

Comment: Can you please do with RDD

Comment: what is the use of going back to RDD when DF is there? plase use DF since it is efficient and faster!. please accept the answer if this solves your problem.